# how to create the automate username and password in bash script in centos

Tags: linux, bash, centos

Hi everyone i am wondering if anyone could help me for bash script  in centos to making 4 groups and Adding 8 user with password to each groups, considering the password should be automated  , i mean the bash script need to performs WITHOUT ANY HUMAN INTERVENTION.

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working? Please update your post with these details. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use script like this

`#!/bin/bash
groups=(gr1 gr2 gr3 gr4)
users=(us1 us2 us3 us4)
for i in ${groups[@]}; do
  groupadd $i
done
for i in ${users[@]}; do
    pw=head /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 15 ; echo ''
    echo $i'  '$pw
    useradd $i
    usermod --password $(openssl passwd -1 $pw) $i
    for j in ${groups[@]}; do
       usermod -a -G $j $i
    done
done`

Comment: Tanks , I will trying that

Comment: i have tried that but didn't work it says: groupadd : permission denied also has error in line 8 about this symbol  "  and error in line 23  about suspected end but i cant see line 23 so i don't know what dose mean , anyway tanks for helping me